# switch case inside loop

Tags: c, while-loop, switch-statement

I've run into a slight problem with my function. When I typed in 8 I want it to quit. However when I type 8, it prints out my default message then quits. What have I missed?

```
void Selection()
{
    int selection;

    while (selection != 8)
    {
        printMenu();
        scanf("%d", &selection);
        switch (selection)
        {
            case '1': /*FUNCTION HERE*/ ; break;
            case '2': /*FUNCTION HERE*/ ; break;
            case '3': /*FUNCTION HERE*/ ; break;
            case '4': /*FUNCTION HERE*/ ; break;
            case '5': /*FUNCTION HERE*/ ; break;
            case '6': /*FUNCTION HERE*/ ; break;
            case '7': /*FUNCTION HERE*/ ; break;
            case '8': break;
            default: printf("Unkown command please try again.\n"); break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `int selection;` --> `int selection = -1;` otherwise *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: characters and ints are different things. `8 != '8'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line

```
scanf("%d", &selection);
```

inputs an `int` value, say `8`. But in your `case` statement

```
case '8': break;
```

you are testing a *character* value. Please change all those `case` statements to such as

```
case 8: break;
```

Also, you must initialise the local variable `selection` before you first test it. Compiler should have warned you about that.